# How to check if a video can be supported by device or not on Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I try below code to play *.mp4 video:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(id);
vv.setVideoURI(uri);
```

The path are *.mp4 format.
But sometimes the video are not supported by device which due to the *.mp4 video are not standard codec of mpeg4.
Or the resolution of video higher than device supported.
I want to find them, and show some message.
How can I do to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
vv.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        ...
    }
});
```

For the list of possible error codes see the documentation: [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK)